# Opencart - can't upload images

Tags: opencart

I moved a OpenCart version 1.5.6.4 installation from one server to another and after some time I noticed I can't upload images anymore. Whenever I use the image manager to upload the images it just gets stuck, the spinner wheel keeps spinning but the images are not uploading.

I tried changing the folder pemissions of the image and data folders to 777 and cleared the cache. I also tried to upload an extension that allows for multiple files uploads hoping that somehow magically it would fix the problem, needless to say, it didn't. Haven't found a solution on SO or OC forums.

My best guess is that the problem lies in the config files.

I runned a `phpinfo();` and you can check it at http://atelier-faiblesse.ro/info.php.

The admin config contains the following code:

```
<?php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://atelier-faiblesse.ro/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'http://atelier-faiblesse.ro/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://atelier-faiblesse.ro/admin/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'http://atelier-faiblesse.ro/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/var/www/clients/client9/web72/web/admin/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/var/www/clients/client9/web72/web/system/');
define('DIR_DATABASE', '/var/www/clients/client9/web72/web/system/database/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/var/www/clients/client9/web72/web/admin/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/var/www/clients/client9/web72/web/admin/view/template/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', '/var/www/clients/client9/web72/web/system/config/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/var/www/clients/client9/web72/web/image/');
define('DIR_CACHE', '/var/www/clients/client9/web72/web/system/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/var/www/clients/client9/web72/web/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', '/var/www/clients/client9/web72/web/system/logs/');
define('DIR_CATALOG', '/var/www/clients/client9/web72/web/catalog/');

// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysqli');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'XXXXXXXX');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'XXXXXXXX');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'XXXXXXXX');
define('DB_PREFIX', 'oc_');
?>
```

Do you notice any problems in the config file? Or do you know any other reasons file uploading might not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run below commands from ssh to fix this issue.

chown -R www-data /var/www/clients/client9/web72/web/image
chmod -R 755 /var/www/clients/client9/web72/web/image